# Update a column based on two matching values of a column in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlanywhere

I have two questions which if someone can help me it would be great and would be a great learning for me.

1. I have two tables and my requirement is to update a column `A` of
   `Table 1` value only for those rows for which the column `B` has
   values same as column `B` of `Table2`.

   I am looking for an optimized query for this in SQL.

   ```
   UPDATE DBA.COM, DBA.MEN
   SET DBA.COM.ND_MAN=''
   WHERE DBA.MEN
   ```

   After this, I couldn't select column names in where condition.
2. The problem I am finding in Column `B` of both the tables is, it is
   unique identified (GUID) from the UI. So, when I copy the cell value
   from "SQL Anywhere" Interactive SQL Editor, it displays the column
   value copied as follows:

   ```
   0x99e2f2a23f9946acb0ceb374a627b142
   ```

   and not as `99e2f2a23f9946acb0ceb374a627b142`.

   However, both the table's column value when I copy, it is starting
   with `0x`. So will it not pose any problem I guess?

Or how to rectify it in above query which you will create for question 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join and update something as

```
update table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.B = t2.B
set t1.A = 'some value'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however, the "." i.e t1.B is not fetching column names of table :( Its SQL Anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work as I sayd. Because, I am not able to first give an alias and also it is not fetching columns on my editor. Not a intellisense problem also, because other queries works properly with intellisense

Comment: can you add the query to the question that you are trying ?

Comment: Updated it Abhik, please see

Comment: hmm just try without alias i.e. directly as `JOIN table1.B = table2.B set table1.A = 'some val'`

Comment: Just checked the doc of sql anywhere and they explicitly use the word INNER JOIN , but just JOIN means INNER JOIN in many RDBMS thats pretty interesting.

Comment: Abhi, thank you, I tried this, it works perfectly fine UPDATE DBA.COM, DBA.MEN
SET DBA.COM.N_MAN=''
WHERE DBA.COM.MEN_ID = DBA.MEN.MEN_ID AND 
IP_STAT ='O' OR IP_STAT = 'T'

Comment: Abhik, thank you, but my above query works without using JOIN keyword at all but just the where conditions. Remember, there was no intellisense availble only for this case, so, I just thought to give a try and run and it worked :)

Comment: And Deepak, one more thing, the column values starting with "0X" is also resolved because, both table column values start with "0X" :)Thank you again, appreciate your help, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first question

```
UPDATE t1, t2 SET t1.name = new_value WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

Notes:

```
A multiple-table UPDATE is an extension of a single-table statement:

Following the UPDATE keyword, name the tables involved in the operation, separated by
commas. (You must name all the tables used in the query, even if you aren’t updating all
of them.)

In the WHERE clause, describe the conditions that determine how to match records in the
tables.

In the SET clause, assign values to the columns to be updated. These assignments can
refer to columns from any of the joined tables.
```

Comment: Why t2 you are updating?

Comment: The query does not updates table t2. Tables which you see after UPDATE keyword are the tables which are included in update query. Only the tables specified after SET clause are updated. You can read my notes for more information.

Comment: Deepak, thank you, however, sadly I do not get the column names by placing dot. i.e t1. doesn't fetch ID. I am using SQL Anywhere. Please advise